# Root level category, tag, author and archive pages to work

Tags: categories, permalinks, tags, archives, author

I want root level Wordpress urls to work for category, tag, author and archive page.
For example right now categories pages are.

```
domain.com/category/cat-name/
```

it shows posts under cat-name category.
But if someone visits

```
domain.com/category/
```

it shows 404 error, page not found.
I want all these URLs to show some unique content created specifically for each link.

```
domain.com/category/
domain.com/tag/
domain.com/author/
domain.com/archive/
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible by default. Your only possible way out of this is to create custom [**page templates**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) which you can modify to display something like an index or any custom content

When you create a new page in the back-end, choose this custom template, and make sure that your page slugs is named accordingly so that when you visit

> domain.com/category/

that this custom page template is being displayed

Comment: Yes of course, we can create a page and set permalink accordingly. But will it not interfere with standard permalink structure of categories and everything else.

Comment: No, it will be fine to use, no problems. Remember, these base pages has nothing assigned to them, that is why they 404 by default

Comment: Okay I tried it on a empty test installation. And it seems to be working for 'domain.com/category/' page. But if we create a subpage 'domain.com/category/subpage/' under this category page. It shows 404 error. It appears Wordpress considers it as category, whatever is after '/category/' in URL. Same applies to other too.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. You cannot assign any subpage to that page, as it will break the hierarchy. Wordpress will look for the category `subpage`, which does not exists, that is why it 404's. I thought you just needed something to show when you go to domain.com/category/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am only looking for a way to display some content on root level pages. And it's working that way. It's just that I am little concerned. That's all. :) Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: No need to be concerned. Enjoy :-)